# Filtering a numeric vector based on whether the number is an integer or not

Tags: r, vector

I need a function (bespoke or from a package) that can filter a numeric vector based on whether the number is an integer or not.

So in the following vector

```
vec <- c(1.0, 5.0, 5.3, 10.0, 2.5)
```

I would want it to come out

```
integerFunction(vec)

[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

I know R has special classes for numeric and integers but that is not what I am talking about. I need to find integers *within* a numeric class vector (i.e. where the value after the decimal is greater than 0)

Comment: For your example you could do `vec <- c(1.0, 5.0, 5.3, 10.0, 2.5); integerFunction <- function(vec) {round(vec, 0) == vec}; integerFunction(vec)` but there are many, many "gotcha's" to this type of problem, e.g. is -1.0 an integer? Is 1.00000000000000001 an integer? I'm sure this has been discussed at length on SO before

Comment: A good question @jared_mamrot, but well above my pay grade. Number theory need not come into it though since I want to flag clusters of observations where there are ties using `rank()`. Never more than four or five observations in a cluster so no danger of infinitesimal decimals (good band name? the Infinitesimal Decimals?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `floor`

```
integerFunction <- function(x) {
  x - floor(x) == 0
}
integerFunction(c(1.0, 5.0, 5.3, 10.0, 2.5))

[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach just in case this helps someone.
A float value is seen as an integer if it has no remainder when divided by one.

```
integerFunction <- function(x) {
  (x %% 1) == 0 
}

vec <- c(1.0, 5.0, 5.3, 10.0, 2.5)
integerFunction(vec)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks @Kota Mori, very nice solution. What is a 'float value'?

Comment: Float is a general term for the `numeric` type on R.  Numbers possibly with decimal part.

Comment: Can you explain what the `%%` does?

Comment: `%%` is the modulo operator.  `x %% y` returns the remainder when `x` is divided by `y`.

Comment: I don't understand. When I ran `4.3 %% 2` it returned `0.3`.

Comment: `2 * 2 = 4`, leaving `0.3` to get to `4.3` - it's the *remainder* that is returned by `%%`